# Adding percent sign (%) to formula field in quote line items

Tags: fields, formatting

If I add the Standard field Discount to quote line items than the discount will show up right justified with the percent sign to the right of the value.  If I create a Custom field of type Formula(Percent) or just a Percent field I get the value but no percent sign %.  Is there a way to format that field so that it shows up with a percent sign?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a custom Text Formula Field and then add in the % symbol. The only drawback (off the top of my head) would be that it won't work as a real percentage in Reports.

Comment: One method is to label the field as "Display" and the actual number fields as "Report %" 

For example: "Discount % Reportable" and "Discount % Display"